# (C#, WinForms) How to assign an accessibility attribute to an image in ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility, imagelist

I'm trying to find a way to make a screen-reader (like JAWS) to read out loud some text that is assigned to images in ImageList.

In other controls (like PushButton) there is "AccessibleName" property, that when contains text, it's being read by JAWS.

the ImageList consists of four icons that represent priorities, and no text is displayed near them.

Is it possible to do it?
Can you think of any other creative solution?

Thanks, Yaniv.

Answer (score 1):

An `ImageList` isn't really a visible control - it is a resource. IIRC you would have to associate accessibility concerns with the control that is *using* the `ImageList`.

Comment: Thanks Marc,

The ImageList itself should not be associated with a text to be read; the single images in that list should have it, but after exploring the Image class i wasn't able to come up with a solution.

The design is something like that:
A form with a TreeView, in which the TreeNodes are dynamically created and associated with the appropriate image from the ImageList.

Exploring the TreeNode object also yielded nothing.

We can always add a descriptive text near the icon, but that's the least desired solution.

Thanks, Yaniv.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not an AccessibleName or AccessibleDescription property on the TreeNode object? Then, as you are building the dynamic node, and associating a specific image to it from the imagelist, you can also have some code that 'calculates' the accessible text for the image and sets one of those properties.